# Android ContentObserver

Tags: android, listview, android-cursor

I have a Cursor 'c' that generates a ListView. The Content Provider ensures that the ListView gets updated whenever the underlying data changes. However, I want to additionally make a call to another function to update my Header/Footer views everytime the listview is drawn.

How does one implement this with ContentObservers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void listenChanges() {
 context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CONTENT_URI, true,
 new MyContentObserver());
}

public class MyContentObserver extends android.database.ContentObserver {

 public MyContentObserver() {
  super(null);
 }

 @Override
 public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
  super.onChange(selfChange);
  //Do all you need here
 }
}
```